# if cell contains exact text then display

Tags: excel

Hi I have a simple dummy dataset like this one below, what I want to do is to return "TRUE" if Column A contains "S120". I used this formula to try to get my desired result

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("S120",A2)),TRUE,FALSE)`

However this is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akn86.png) I received

What I want is to print is "TRUE" if the cell matches EXACTLY "S120", so, if the cell contains "S1200" it prints "FALSE"

Comment: Please show some examples of the data.  I assume `S120` and `S1200` are not the only text in the cell.

Comment: `=A2="S120"` perhaps?

Comment: @BigBen Hi Thanks for replying, this actually worked, I did not expect the formula to be this simple. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula in cell B2 and drag it down column B:
`=(A2="S120")`

Comment: Yes, but they might make the formula easier to understand. (I didn't notice your comment before posting my answer.)

Comment: I mean, it's a pretty simple formula... as OP [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64067329/if-cell-contains-exact-text-then-display/64067492?noredirect=1#comment113292892_64067329). :-)